# Exceeds file size is returning true when it shouldn't

Tags: php, if-statement, file-upload

I have a upload script where users can upload images. I have a condition to verify if the file size is greater than 2 megabytes. but it is returning false for images of less than 2 megabytes.

Any suggestions?

```
$image = $_FILES['image'] ?? '';

if (!has_max_file_size($image)) {
    $errors['images'] = 'File too large. File must be less than 2 megabytes. ';
}

function has_max_file_size($file)
{
  return $file['size'] > 2097152; // 2 MB
}
```

Comment: You have your logic backwards. Your function returns if the file size is larger than 2097152, then throwing an error if the returned value is false.

Comment: @aynber Ah I see, I got it thanks for your help